# Where does the module parameter stored while loading a driver module with module parameter

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, build-automation

Where does the module parameter stored while loading a driver module with module parameter.I need to automate such that if i load a module it will load with that parameter enabled. eg
if I need to load a module net_dev.ko with a module parameter hw_enable=1
So I need to do-

```
modprobe net_dev hw_enable=1
```

to load it with that option
But I want when I do-

```
modprobe net_dev
```

It will automatically take hw_enable=1
So for that where should i kept this module parameter in the kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options are provided in the configuration file for the module to be installed in the /etc/modprobe.d/ directory. So in your case if you create a file net_dev.conf in /etc/modprobe.d directory with the following line

options net_dev hw_enable=1

and you call modprobe net_dev, it should execute modprobe net_dev hw_enable=1